# How to keep the window manage in the central screen

Tags: 12.04, screen

so this is a question of multiple displays. I am using three displays along my laptop in Ubuntu 12.04. When I press alt-tab the window manage appears on the screen that I am working, that is, if I am working on the left display the window manager will appear there.

My question then is:
Is there a way to make that the window manager always appear on the central display / screen?